# Start an embedded video when countdown reaches 0

Tags: javascript, html, video, display

I´ve got an javascript countdown from w3schools. And I want a video to start when the countdown hits 0. The countdown and the video is in the same div. I am not very good at js. I've figured out how to write texts after the counter hits 0 but not to call for the embedded video. Instead it gets overwritten I believe.

```
The script:

var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 12, 2017 14:48:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)";
}, 1000);

    }
}, 1000);
```

My div

```
<div class="font-size-96 text-align-center luminant-color container-1" id="demo">
 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-JTLN9cyOaw?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&autoplay=1&amp;start=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a million other ways to do this with the YouTube API, but, if you want a quick fix, you can essentially reload the video by resetting the iframe source at the timeout. Instead of getting the id of the demo div, get the iframe, and switch the 'autoplay' parameter in the src. DONT set the 'demo' div's innerHTML --> this is why your code is getting rewritten, because you are overwriting the iframe, which is part of the demo div HTML.

```js
// get the iframe element and set its autoplay equal to 0 to keep it from playing immediately;
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe-demo');
iframe.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/-JTLN9cyOaw?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&autoplay=0&amp';

// your code
var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 12, 2017 14:48:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    // overwriting the HTML here will erase the iframe, so remove it!
   // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + //"d " + hours + "h "
 //   + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
        // set autoplay equal to 1 at the timeout so the video plays; WARNING: this will reload the video. not a huge deal, but a hack;
         iframe.src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/-JTLN9cyOaw?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&autoplay=1&amp';
}, 1000);

    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="font-size-96 text-align-center luminant-color container-1" id="demo">
  <iframe id="iframe-demo" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-JTLN9cyOaw?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&autoplay=1&amp;start=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. However, with the new code I cannot get it to display the timer. Now the countdown gets replaced by by one version of the videoplayer with autoplay=0. and then when the date in the code passes the videoplayer switches to a player with autoplay=1. It is what I'm looking for but the countdown display is not showing. Any further suggestions? 

Best regards